# Simulate Rocket League Quick Chat

Tags: code-golf

In [Rocket League](https://www.rocketleague.com/), there are controls assigned to quick chat. For PC, they are
`1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`. To use a quick chat, you must press two controls. For example, the first option would be `1`, `1`.

You will be simulating the Rocket League client. You will be given a non-empty list composed only of four characters of your choosing. The length of the list will always be even and `<= 8`. I will be using `1, 2, 3, 4` for the examples. If you modify the input domain, you must specify how your input maps to `1, 2, 3, 4`.

The first character in each couplet specifies the section, the second the item in the section. Below are all sections, with their default chat:

```
1
 1 I got it!
 2 Need boost!
 3 Take the shot!
 4 Defending...

2
 1 Nice shot!
 2 Great pass!
 3 Thanks!
 4 What a save!

3
 1 OMG!
 2 Noooo!
 3 Wow!
 4 Close one!

4
 1 $#@%!
 2 No problem.
 3 Whoops...
 4 Sorry!
```

The above are case sensitive. So, `1 1` would be `I got it!`, and `3 3` would be `Wow!`.

In addition, after three quick chats come through rapidly, the game shots you down. You get a message back: `Chat disabled for 2 seconds.`. If you continue trying, you get one more chance, and then `Chat disabled for 4 seconds.`. Our challenge will not deal with time, or any further chats.

However, after three chats (6 input characters), you must output `Chat disabled for 2 seconds.`. After four chats (8 input characters), you must output `Chat disabled for 4 seconds.`. Since 8 is the maximum input length, that would be your final output, if they are 8 input characters.

## Input

First, chose your four characters, and map them to `1, 2, 3, 4`.

Your input will be non-empty, contain an even number of items, and only contain up to eight items.

## Output

You will output the matching quick chats in order, plus any `chat disabled` warnings (in the correct location). Output is case sensitive. It must be delimited - suggested delimiters are `\n` (pretty delimiter) or `,`, and you cannot use any delimiters in any of the possible outputs.

## Test Cases

In these, input is in the form of a JSON list and can be `1, 2, 3, 4`, and the output delimiter is `,`.

```
[1, 1, 1, 1] => I got it!,I got it!
[2, 4, 4, 4] => What a save!,Sorry!
[3, 3] => Wow!
[1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4] => Defending...,Thanks!,$#@%!,Chat disabled for 2 seconds.,Sorry!,Chat disabled for 4 seconds.
```

Invalid (out of scope) inputs:

```
[] //empty
[1, 3, 1] //odd length
[5, 4] //character out of input domain
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1] //length > 8
```

To ensure the point is made: you are not taking these in real time, like in the game. You are just receiving a (short) list of numbers.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/63370/what-am-i-even-saying), though I am in favor of closing the old one as a duplicate of this.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien oh, didn't see that. They are kinda different, since mine is multiple inputs. We'll see what the community thinks. Guess I shoulda posted this to Sandbox after all :/

Comment: It's fine. I personally like this challenge better (being the writer of the aforementioned challenge). The concept is essentially the same, with the only difference being multiple inputs and the lack of a bonus. The latter, at least, is good.

Comment: @StephenS opps sorry. Forgot I had insta edit

Comment: @Christopher oh right, no problem. I have to get used to that too :)

Comment: Shouldn't `4 3` be `Whoops...` not `Wow!`?

Comment: Is the input limited to a list of characters, i.e. a string? Or may it be a list of integers? Everything looks like integers, but you say characters.

Comment: @musicman523 I've edited the input of this example

Comment: @JonathanAllan you can do whatever you want. I say characters because you can change the input domain if you want. You can accept a string list or an int list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>153</s> 150 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁶;j@“Kẋ3ŒK!D“¿ṁxṁị»Wḣ
J_2ḤÇ€
s2ḅ4ị“w eɲEƓṫ:⁾ṆƙḅƙḣḊṗṠ,`ė)®=Œf°Ẇŀ#ḍḤḌCṭ8v⁻$ʠṄṾŻYtṫʠßR>ĊḷḊc8Þ@Zq8-@⁻⁺ ḃḊĿ`ÆYƒðḤ|3ƓULẇẇŻịỵ1²ṄE'Cṣ\{ṣ{ḃ⁵ḳpẸz.4<»Ỵ¤µżÇ;/ȦÐfY
```

Input is a list of integers, where `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3` represent `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4` respectively.
Output is a newline separated print out.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#FY5NS8NAEIbv/RW1CiL40TY9BKsS0F6sJ0ElIlgQe/CkKCrWQ@NHAm0FSQ9FEA2kePGDUo3uZqWF3W7Q/ovZPxJHmHlhZt55ZmJlfeb3DFW9L0JY16RbHFnCgveBWqeYwOqcbQDxE8vbWSBt4aiLl8Q6yiGW1zmco/0kufvbLURNoM@zyuoBtaM7nP6LD6QGtAXUmywNWhP8bV66Zd6B0JbVUSA3yATSWAT6qh8ri40NPaBXQHuSmUeIG3ricXVhUAPyhaAdXTwYmwf6lIFWZYVJIJfYHvRLwjYjV3SQdq5FzbUVCB0MyfA/YEGGd5FaGMcz/lYFpYKLygqAvO9DSM6mc3McrR@8zQP5LZz8zM@TuC2bcRyn0lomq6U1LfUH)**

#### How?

There is a compressed string taking up 105 bytes:

```
“w eɲEƓṫ:⁾ṆƙḅƙḣḊṗṠ,`ė)®=Œf°Ẇŀ#ḍḤḌCṭ8v⁻$ʠṄṾŻYtṫʠßR>ĊḷḊc8Þ@Zq8-@⁻⁺ ḃḊĿ`ÆYƒðḤ|3ƓULẇẇŻịỵ1²ṄE'Cṣ\{ṣ{ḃ⁵ḳpẸz.4<»
= "Need boost!\nTake the shot!\nDefending...\nNice shot!\nGreat pass!\nThanks!\nWhat a save!\nOMG!\nNoooo!\nWow!\nClose one!\n$#@%!\nNo problem.\nWhoops...\nSorry!\nI got it!"
```

(Somewhat shockingly 1 byte was saved by including all the `!` rather than inserting them via code.)

The program then works as follows

```
⁶;j@“Kẋ3ŒK!D“¿ṁxṁị»Wḣ - Link 1, get a disabled string: number, seconds
⁶                     - space character
 ;                    - concatenate with seconds (e.g. " 4")
    “Kẋ3ŒK!D“¿ṁxṁị»   - compressed list of strings ["Chat disabled for"," seconds"]
  j@                  - join (swap @arguments)  (e.g. "Chat disabled for 4 seconds"
                   W  - wrap in a list
                    ḣ - head to seconds (for -2 and 0 gives an empty list, for 2 and 4 give the string wrapped in a list)

J_2ḤÇ€ - Link 2, get disabled strings: list of chat strings
J      - range of length (e.g. for 4 chat strings [1,2,3,4])
 _2    - subtract 2      (...[-1,0,1,2])
   Ḥ   - double          (...[-2,0,2,4])
    Ç€ - call last link (1) as a monad for €ach

s2ḅ4ị“...»Ỵ¤µżÇ;/ȦÐfY - Main link: list of characters
s2                    - split into twos
  ḅ4                  - convert from base four (vectorises)
           ¤          - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
     “...»            -   compressed string described in code-block above
          Ỵ           -   split on newlines
    ị                 - index into (use the base four representation to get the chat strings)
            µ         - monadic chain separation (call that x)
              Ç       - call last link (2) as a monad
             ż        - zip
               ;/     - flatten list by one level
                  Ðf  - filter keep if:
                 Ȧ    -   any and all (false for empty results, i.e. the empty results from link 2)
                    Y - join with newlines
                      - implicit print
```

Comment: List of ints is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 264 bytes

```
f=([x,y,...z],n=.5)=>"I got it!,Need boost!,Take the shot!,Defending...,Nice shot!,Great pass!,Thanks!,What a save!,OMG!,Noooo!,Wow!,Close one!,$#@%!,No problem.,Whoops...,Sorry!".split`,`[x*4+y-5]+(n>1?`,Chat disabled for ${n} seconds.`:'')+(z[0]?','+f(z,n*2):'')
```